# Trying to delete an row from pandas Dataframe based on some conditon on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a working professional doing my Mtech and trying to do a project on machine learning. I;m new to python as well as ML. I have a column called as Found and this has multiple values. I want to delete all the rows which is not matching a specific condition mentioned based on found column

```
    df['Found']

0          developement
1          func-test
2          func-test
3         regression
4          func-test
5        integration
6          func-test
7          func-test
8         regression
9          func-test
```

I want to keep the rows which has Found value as "anything that has test and regression

I wrote the following code.

```
remove_list = []
for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    text = df.iloc[x]['Found']
    if not re.search('test|regression', text, re.I):
        remove_list.append(x)
print(remove_list) 
df.drop(remove_list, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

but the remove_list is empty. am i doing anything wrong here? or is there a better way of achieving this?

```
[]
      Identifier Status  Priority  Severity         Found       Age  \
0     Bug 1      V       NaN         2         development        1   
1     Bug 2      R       NaN         6         func-test         203   
2     Bug 3      V       NaN         2         func-test          9   
3     Bug 4      D       NaN         3        regression          4   
4     Bug 5      V       NaN         2        func-test           9
```

I even tried this but i get the following error:

```
for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    if not re.search('test|regression|customer', df.iloc[x]['Found'], re.I):
        df.drop(x, inplace = True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-14f97ad6d00a> in <module>
      1 for x in range(df.shape[0]):
----> 2     if not re.search('test|regression|customer', df.iloc[x]['Found'], re.I):
      3         df.drop(x, inplace = True)

~/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/nlp_course/lib/python3.7/re.py in search(pattern, string, flags)
    183     """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    184     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 185     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
    186 
    187 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this concisely with [**`.str.contains()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and boolean indexing:

```py
df = df[df['Found'].str.contains('test|regression')]

#   Identifier Status  Priority  Severity       Found  Age
# 1      Bug 2      R       NaN         6   func-test  203
# 2      Bug 3      V       NaN         2   func-test    9
# 3      Bug 4      D       NaN         3  regression    4
# 4      Bug 5      V       NaN         2   func-test    9
```

If you need to handle `nan`, prepend [**`replace(np.nan, '')`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```py
df = df[df['Found'].replace(np.nan, '').str.contains('test|regression')]
```

---

And as [@sophocles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9167382/sophocles) mentioned, you could also make it case-insensitive with `case=False`:

```py
df = df[df['Found'].str.contains('test|regression', case=False)]
```

Comment: you can even make it case insensitive, with ```str.contains('test|regression',case=False)]```..

Comment: if I am not mistaken, I think the ```case=False``` should be in the bracket.  Please test it :)

Comment: Yes.. case=False is within bracket. and it works fine.

Comment: Looks like i have to remove the NaN values before passing it on to a dataframe.        df = df[df['Found'].notna()] and then df = df[df['Found'].str.contains('test|regression', case=False)] works. anyway to handle it dynamically. I cannot use dropna() since i hace a column priority with most of NaN values

Comment: @Sai You can handle the NaNs inline by chaining an extra `replace()` like so: `df = df[df['Found'].replace(np.nan, '').str.contains('test|regression')]`